# When do you check for terror in an encounter?

Tags: deadlands-classic, morale

When facing an abomination with a terror rating, when is the terror check triggered in the encounter? Is there only one check per encounter?

Answer (score 2):

The terror check is triggered when the combatants **first** become aware of the abomination. There is only **one** such check per encounter.

This is excluding certain Edges (Nerves of Steel, maybe - I might be getting that name confused with an "All Flesh Must Be Eaten" Quality) that can allow a player to forgo the check.